# PHP APC: includepath from the previous request is used instead of current

Tags: php, include-path

For some reason my classes are not loaded correctly. They are either failing to load, or the wrong version of the class is loaded (taken from the wrong directory).

After some debugging, it became apparent that the include path that is used is in fact the include path from the previous request.

However, when I run `get_include_path()` the logged result is correct, but it's clear from the behavior that in practice it's not used, and instead used the path from the previous request.

My code is PHP with the Yii framework. The framework manipulates `includepath` at runtime.

PHP versions is `5.31` , xampp, windows7

edit: disabling apc solved the problem

Comment: So why do you have different versions of the same class in your application?

Comment: For some good reasons, that are not really related to the topic of the current issue

Comment: Restart apache.  I've seen issues like this when APC has been running too long.  Increasing your cache size may help.

Comment: I've restarted the computer since, not only Apache!

Comment: disabling apc solved the problem! I still want to know, what should I do to have normal behavior with apc turned on

Answer (score 1):

I see this pretty regularly with APC.  Most often, when APC fills up.

Run the [apc.php](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/apc/tags/APC_3_1_3/apc.php?revision=287244&view=co) script (included with most APC installs) in your browser to check your utilization.  Ouput looks like this:
[image: apc ouptput]

If APC is full, increase the amount of memory allocated to it.  Somewhere in your PHP config, there's a config option controlling this: `apc.shm_size=64`.  This allocates 64 meg of ram.  Increase it until you have some breathing room.  You'll need to restart apache for this change to take effect.

If you deploy your application to a different path on disk every time, you should probably purge APC -- otherwise the old cache entries tend to linger.  The easiest way to do this is with a graceful restart of your webserver.  Note that on an active production server, this will interrupt active requests for a second or so.

Comment: My distribution (xampp) doesn't seem to have such a file. Can I get this information by some other means (command line for example)?

Comment: Let's say I enlarge it, won't it fill up anyway one day? Is this a proper handling of full cache situation?

Comment: apc.php really is going to be the best way to investigate APC utilization.  Note that PHP CLI cannot give you info about what's going on inside your apache instance, because it's a separate executable -- it doesn't have access to mod_php's shared memory.  APC will not fill up if you 1) have a steady set of files for it to cache [it will eventually cache them all, and stop growing] or 2) You purge its cache regularly [every n deploys].

Comment: Added a link to the source of apc.php directly from svn: http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/apc/tags/APC_3_1_3/apc.php?revision=287244&view=co

Comment: Well, it's definititely a good idea to check this, but it appears that I have 92% free

Comment: Keep an eye on it, and especially check it if you see this error again.  Also, make sure to look at "cache full count", which is reported on the left side of apc.php.  I try to keep this at zero.