# Resetting any server / php cache

Tags: php, caching

Some very strange stuff ( [PHP APC: includepath from the previous request is used instead of current](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5561275/440925)) is going on on my local env, which doesn't happen with the same code base on other environments. So I suspect some caching problem is going on

What steps should I perform, to make sure all possible (server side) cache is cleared?

My code is a php web application with apache xampp server, windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you resolve to full paths, which is faster anyway.

Example:

```
define('HOME', dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
include(HOME . 'file.php');
```